# Cannot select text with iFrame on iOS devices (webkit)

Tags: html, ios, css, iframe, mobile

It seems that mobile selection on iOS devices does not work correctly when text is contained within an iFrame that is offset (padded, margined) from the top of the page.

In the example below, if one opens the page: https://viking2917.github.io/mobileselectionbug/
on an iOS mobile browser, and them tap-and-hold on the word "amet" in the first line to select it, then attempt to expand the selection by dragging the text selection drag handles, the drag handle will immediately jump down to near the bottom of page, and if you drag it around you will see the drag handle is offset from your finger (looks like by the amount the iFrame is offset from the top of the page).

The HTML to reproduce this (hosted at the link above):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div>
    <div style="height: 200px;"></div>
    <iframe srcdoc="<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam dignissim neque nec ante suscipit semper. Sed sit amet rutrum metus, in mattis ante. Quisque at nunc tellus. Maecenas ut rhoncus erat, sit amet ultricies augue. Aliquam et consectetur mauris. Pellentesque porttitor accumsan pretium. Vivamus risus lorem, varius in laoreet vel, interdum nec metus. Nam gravida vehicula lorem at lobortis. Curabitur sit amet libero ut nulla fermentum volutpat sed at mauris. Ut mollis at tellus vel tincidunt. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Integer lacinia iaculis odio, sed tincidunt massa accumsan a. Aliquam arcu urna, ullamcorper sagittis nunc eu, facilisis tempor felis. Ut fermentum justo in risus ullamcorper, tempus viverra neque venenatis. Aenean lectus sapien, interdum ut congue non, hendrerit sed diam. Suspendisse ante tellus, luctus eget ex eu, faucibus porttitor nulla.</p><p> Aliquam iaculis placerat tincidunt. Donec justo ligula, dictum ac volutpat accumsan, molestie eu est. Pellentesque lectus est, elementum sed finibus non, scelerisque a nunc. Cras id ornare turpis. Quisque consequat erat turpis. Vestibulum ut nulla feugiat, pretium eros et, dignissim nisi. Sed et finibus turpis. Morbi viverra vulputate lacus.</p><p>Sed in lorem laoreet, gravida metus nec, cursus nunc. Proin dignissim elit id urna imperdiet commodo. Nullam laoreet elementum risus vel tristique. Praesent aliquam ante id nibh condimentum, in semper lectus porta. Proin commodo leo sit amet finibus consectetur. Nam posuere lorem elit, at eleifend odio lobortis nec. Aenean ultricies tellus nec nunc porta, id hendrerit dui malesuada. Aliquam vel lacus feugiat tellus fermentum sollicitudin. Suspendisse consectetur ipsum ac ligula tincidunt molestie. Aenean vel ex eget justo pretium sodales eu sed lectus. Quisque malesuada rutrum tincidunt. Cras sit amet massa pulvinar, fermentum ante in, tristique diam. Etiam nec semper mauris. Donec ultricies purus ut est scelerisque eleifend imperdiet accumsan mi.</p>">
    </iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can't see that I'm doing anything wrong, any ideas?

Really feels like a browser bug. This is broken on mobile Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

Comment: related discussion at: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=193663

Answer (score 0):

This is an iOS/Safari bug. The fix is in the beta for 12.2, to be released at some point. Details here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=193663